# SQL Relational Division query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

I have three tables student(ID, name), takes(ID, course_id), course(course_id, dept_name).
I would like to query student ID and name who take all courses from dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'.
I know I need to use Relation Division. But I'm not sure how to do.

Can anyone explain how can I achieve this?

PS. I just start learning SQL today.

Comment: You should read up on joins and aggregate functions.

Comment: I've read about them already. I'm pretty sure that I know the basic of SQL including JOIN, aggregate functions, and stuff, but I just have no idea how I should approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this below logic-

```
SELECT S.ID, S.name 
FROM student S 
INNER JOIN takes T ON S.ID = T.ID
INNER JOIN course C ON T.course_id = C.course_id AND C.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'
GROUP BY S.ID, S.name
HAVING COUNT(T.course_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course WHERE dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.')
```

As gordon said about possibility of taking same course twice, we can use the Having clause as below-

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT T.course_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM course WHERE dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.')
```

Comment: You are most welcome @HokhyTann

Comment: @HokhyTann . . . This assumes that no student takes a course twice.

Comment: This is not the usual way to express an equivalent to relational division -- see wikipedia and a gazillion other similar questions on SO. This method 'fails' in corner cases (as Gordon points out) -- except the question is so vaguely worded, it's hard to know what's right in those cases.

Answer (score -2):

Just Join all tables and give Where condition

```
`select S.ID,S.name from student s inner join takes t on s.ID = t.ID inner join course c on t.course_id = c.course_id where c.dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.'`
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this solves the problem. It just returns all students that take some courses from CS department but not all of them.

Comment: This is wrong. It returns all Students who take any CompSci course (maybe just one course). The q is looking for students who take *all* CompSci courses -- presumably more than one.